# R how to convert origin-destination matrix to a network considering different values

Tags: r, diagram

I am trying to analyze a huge dataframe that is composed by following fields:

> Code.Origin, Code.Destination, LongitudeOrigin, LongitudeDestination, LatitudeOrigin, LatitudeDestination, QuantityofObjectsTransported

[image]

I would transform this table into a matrix to create a network diagram with nodes and arcs using R. At this point if I had the network diagram it would be easy analyze quantities for each O-D system.

Comment: Hi! Please improve the formatting of you question.